# Moving Laravel models back to the App/ folder root

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel 8 there was a shift to put models into their own `App/Models` folder after they were moved to the `App/` root in Laravel 5.

However Laravel has always supported the ability to switch back for those who preferred it.

I learned Laravel with version 5, so I prefer models being in the `App/` root.

How can I move models back to where they were in Laravel 5-7 and still have Laravel 10+ function correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps for putting models back in the `App/` root are very minimal, and Laravel will detect you've done them so `make:model` will work as expected.

1. Edit `config/auth.php` so that the users model entry points to the correct namespace:

   ```
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
   ```
2. Move your `Users.php` model (and any other models you have) into the `App/` root. **Then delete the models directory.**
3. Once they're moved, ensure the namespace is correct for each of the models.

   ```
    namespace App;
   ```

That's all you need to do!

To test it's worked correctly, you can ask PHP Artisan to create a new model for you:

```
    > php artisan make:model Test
```

You should see `Test.php` in the `App/` root.

---

**Important Note:** [Laravel Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze-installation) doesn't support this out of the box, but the quick fix is to simply search and replace `App\Models\User;` with `App\User;`.

There is one controller (RegisteredUserController.php), one request (ProfileUpdateRequest.php), and six tests that Breeze adds, that will be updated by this search/replace. Very simple.

If you encounter any problems when running the default tests, make sure you run `composer dump-autoload` after making the above changes.